# Is this possible to save the pdf file data into the database using java programming?

Tags: java, mysql, pdf, pdfbox

I have already converted pdf file in the format of text to read bt it is possible to save text data into database...

Comment: Short answer, yes. Long answer, you need to be more specific in your question. What about saving to the database do you have an issue with or is it something about the pdf file?

Comment: What precisely is your problem *"saving text data into database"*?

Comment: Actually my project name is result analysis system so I want to take count of pass and fail students from all students from pdf so what I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. You should create PDF using external library (for example iText) and save it in database as bytes. Or you can save in database only data what needs for create PDF and make it when your client needs it.